# button in header menu php

Tags: php, css, button, header

i created a header.php for my web site.
For my menu, i created 5 buttons. 
When i press on a button it redirect me on the page associated to it.
Until now everything fine.

What i want is, on the current page, my button of the page associated to it change to an other color or background image.

I dont know if we can do that and if i explain myself well.

here my header.php

```
<div id="main_menu">
    <div id="menu_blog"><button onclick="location.href='blog.html'"><h1>Trucs/Astuces</h1></button></div>
    <div id="menu_contact"><button onclick="location.href='/contact.php'"><h1>Contact</h1></button></div>
    <div id="menu_soumission"><button onclick="location.href='/soumission.php'"><h1>Soumission</h1></button></div>
    <div id="menu_realisation"><button onclick="location.href='/realisations.php'">
    <h1>Réalisations</h1></button></div>
    <div id="menu_service"><button onclick="location.href='/services.php'">
    <h1>Services</h1></button></div>
    <div id="menu_a_propos"><button onclick="location.href='/a_propos.php'"><h1>L'entreprise</h1></button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using buttons instead of links? - Also, are you using anything like WordPress or something - or just straight php?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is use CSS

```
#yourbutton:hover{
 background-color: red;
 }
```

or

```
 #yourbutton:active{
  background-color: red;
 }
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to find out what page they are on, and add a class to the "current" page's link.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a GET value with each link

```
<div id="menu_contact"><button onclick="location.href='/contact.php?active=1'"><h1>Contact</h1></button></div>
```

check the value of active in the button

```
< button <?php if ($_GET['active']==1) echo 'class="active"'; ?> ..../>
```

then make a css style for active class

```
.active{

  /*your style here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP page:

```
<div id="main_menu">
    <div id="menu_blog">
        <button onclick="location.href='/blog.html'" <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/blog.html'){echo 'class="currentPage"'; }?>>
            <h1>Trucs/Astuces</h1>
        </button>
    </div>
    … and so on for each menu item ...
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
button.currentPage{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version:

add $current_location to every page and name it after it

```
<?php
$current_location = "a_propos" ;
?>
```

Check if location is correct, then change background color

```
<div id="main_menu">
  <div id="menu_a_propos"><button <?php if ($current_location == "a_propos");?> style=" background-color: red;"<?php };?> onclick="location.href='/a_propos.php'"><h1>L'entreprise</h1></button></div>
</div>
```